# How can I click a button using cefsharp?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Button type:

```
<span class="Pos(r) Z(1) D(ib)">Log in with Facebook</span>
```

I have tried this command:

```
browser1.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.all('Pos(r) Z(1) D(ib)').click()")
```

but nothing happen

Can anyone here can help me?

Comment: Aaand .... what happened?

Comment: @Steve nothing happen dude xD

Comment: Are you trying to click the actual login button on Facebook?